# AWS ELB SSL returns "The private key did not match the public key provided"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, pem

I got the PEM files (with openssl) in order to paste them in `AWS ELB` for https protocol.

In `AWS` in "Select Certificate" window I paste:
[image: Screenshot - select certificate]

1. `Private Key`: private.pem which starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
2. `Public Key Certificate`: public.pem which starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
3. Certificate Chain: Empty

When I Saves it I receive:

[image: Screenshot - Updating Listeners Failed]

Can you help me to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to check the key and cert for typos.

`openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5`

`openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5`

Additionally I had issues in the past with the chain on the load balancer as it sometimes didn't like to order of certificates inside it.

Comment: If you are copying the contents of **.pem** and **.crt** files directly from LINUX - VI editor, you should not do so. Open the files in windows text editor and then paste into AWS form. _I made a similar mistake which was causing this issue._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a mismatch in public-private key pair. Also, AWS recommends to have a certificate chain, otherwise it will consider the server as an unverified SSL.
Seems like you have to regenerate your SSL certificate.

For this you can do the following:-
1. Create SSL private key using OPENSSL.

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out your-private-key-name.pem 2048
```

2. Next, create a CSR key using OPEN-SSL

```
openssl req -sha256 -new -key your-private-key-name.pem -out csr.pem
```

The system will ask for some details, like your country, city, company name etc. Fill in those details.

3. These steps will result in two *.pem* files.
4. Now, while generating your SSL certificate from your SSL provider, generate the SSL certificate using the csr.pem contents.
5. After verification, you will be provided with your SSL certificate (.crt) files. [Generally, two *.crt* files]
6. Now, you have to configure this configuration onto AWS server.
7. Open the form (for which you have posted the screenshot).
   a. For private key section, post the contents of *your-private-key-name.pem* 
   b. Open one of the *.crt* files with a text editor. If this has only one set of 
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- AND -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   paste it in the *Public Key Certificate* section.
   c. If the *.crt* file has multiple sets of 
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- AND -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   paste it in the *Certificate Chain* section.

Now, you have entered your *Private Key*, *Public Key* and *Certificate Chain* AWS should not give any error.

***NOTE:*** *If* you have not purchased a certificate, and are using a self-signed certificate, you can skip the steps (4), (5), (7)-c and leave the *Certificate Chain* blank.

Hope that helps.

### EDIT

Do not copy the contents of *.pem* and *.crt* files directly from LINUX (vi editor). Open the files in windows and then paste the contents into the AWS form. 
*I had a similar issue and this was what i was doing wrong.*

Comment: I see that you are Windows user, you can `cat` the files and then copy the content on linux ;)